# Username and password are correct but I'm still getting ERROR: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045]

Tags: pdo, database-connection

I'm switching from mySql to PDO, but I'm having trouble creating the correct connection to the database. The username and password work in mySql, but I get this error message when I try to connect using the code shown below:

```
ERROR: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'sean'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I'm not really sure why it's saying password 'NO' because I'm definitely using the correct password, and there aren't any users named Sean. Is there something wrong with the syntax I'm using for the username or password?

This is the code I'm using (I'm swapping out 'MyPassword' for the actual password)

```
<?php
session_start(); 
try {
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=MyDatabase', $clickfi4_root, $MyPassword);
  $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM customer_info WHERE id = :id');
  $stmt->execute(array('id' => $id));
  $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
  if ( count($result) ) {
    foreach($result as $row) {
      print_r($row);
    }
  } else {
    echo "No rows returned.";
  }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}      
?>
```

Comment: I don't recommend using the root account for running MySQL queries via PHP.

Comment: @Anton - Out of curiosity, why?

Comment: Security; the root account has unlimited privileges. If you leave vulnerabilities in your php code a hacker could do more damage if the root account is used. For instance, root can drop tables and databases, but you can create a user account that can only SELECT, INSERT, and UPDATE.

Comment: Good point :-) I'll do that as soon as I can get this to work :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the syntax in the [net tuts tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly/) I was using was slightly wrong. It works when I remove the '$' before the username and password :-)

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=MyDatabase', clickfi4_root, MyPassword);
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message said:

```
(using password: NO)
```

Which means a password was not used in the login attempt.

Check the value of $MyPassword.

Also, try using an account other than the root. It's not the best practice anyway.

Comment: I was thrown by the error message too, because I'm definitely using the correct password (I triple-checked). I'm wondering if there's something wrong with the syntax I'm using - $MyPassword (just swapping out 'MyPassword' for the actual password.

Comment: Turns out that the problem had been the syntax I was using for the username and password (I had to remove the '$' in front of them), but now that it's working I'll switch the account I'm using :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes username@127.0.0.1 does the trick instead of username@localhost.

Comment: Turns out that the problem had been the syntax I was using for the username and password (I had to remove the '$' in front of them), but now that it's working I understand what you were suggesting by replacing localhost with 127.0.0.1 :-) I'm sure that will come in handy down the road :-)

Answer (score 0):

For future Googlers, I had the same problem just now and I was pretty sure that password was correct. Yes password was correct indeed but the problem is how I generate password and how I keep password in config file.

If you use a random password generator like me make sure you don't have `$` dollar sign in your password.

If you have `$` in you password then make sure you keep you password in config file like this

```
$pass = 'randomchars$morerandom';
```

but not like this

```
$pass = "randomchars$morerandom";
```